# Which antivirus scans computer without installing?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

I am searching for an antivirus which can run from portable drives so that whenever I get infected computer on my way I can scan it using my drive and clean the infected one and install new one there...

Is there any antivirus for such things?

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://portableapps.com, the Security section has ClamAV that runs off a portable device. But then there's the risk of infecting the portable drive itself.

I'd go for a Live CD like [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net), or [INSERT](http://www.inside-security.de/insert_en.html) (for a smaller distro). There are more listed on the [Knoppix Wiki](http://www.knoppix.net/wiki/Security_Live_CD) too.

Answer (score 1):

There are live CDs from multiple vendors that you can use, see http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [AVG Anti-Virus Rescue USB](http://www.pendriveapps.com/avg-anti-virus-rescue-usb/)

**How to Install AVG to your USB Flash Drive**

1. [Download](http://www.pendriveapps.com/goto/Download/4764/1) the Rescue CD (for USB stick) file
2. Extract the contents of avg_arl_en_90_#.rar to your Flash Drive (I use [7-zip](http://www.pendriveapps.com/goto/7_zip/4764/2) to do this)
3. Click makeboot.bat from the Flash Drive

You should now have a Bootable AVG Flash Drive that you can use to Boot from and scan your Computer for Viruses.

There are lots of antivirus that allow you to create [Bootable AntiVirus Rescue CDs or USB](http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/) and even you can look for the [portable antiviruses for pendrive](http://www.techulator.com/resources/3365-Top-portable-antiviruses-for-pendrive.aspx).

Hope this help..